# Errors structure in Openldap

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap, directory

I have a question concerning Openldap.
I'm using a solution(PingFederate) that gets errors from openldap to do different things depending on the filter. For example i can say : detect the invalid DN Error and when you get it do something.

I've set olcPPolicyUseLockout to true in ppolicy to get more information when there is invalid credentials; so that Pingfederate would catch it. But it doesn't work

When i use the ldapwhoami with -e ppolicy i get the following:
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49); Password expired
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49); Account locked

So my question is the following : What does the semicolon mean in Openldap ?
Is the message after the semicolon taken into account ?
Does Openldap communicate the whole error to the other solutions that it is integrated with ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that the OpenLDAP command-line tools output some textual representation of result code and diagnostic message which is not the exact on-the-wire protocol encoding.

The LDAP PDUs are ASN.1 encoded messages. To understand the response structure you can look into [RFC 4511 section 4.1.9](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511#section-4.1.9). To observe LDAP PDUs actually sent by LDAP components the LDAP dissector in Wireshark is very useful.

Mainly OpenLDAP's overlay [slapo-ppolicy](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-ppolicy) implements [draft-behera-ldap-password-policy-09](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-behera-ldap-password-policy-09). This Internet draft specifys so-called extended controls, both for requests and the responses, which extend the protocol semantics of the bind operation.

This means that each ppolicy-aware LDAP client has to 1. send the [password policy request control](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-behera-ldap-password-policy-09#section-6.1) and 2. decode and interpret the [response control](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-behera-ldap-password-policy-09#section-6.2).

See also [python-ldap demo code](https://github.com/python-ldap/python-ldap/blob/master/Demo/pyasn1/ppolicy.py) as an example.